# Binascii.error: incorrect padding while trying to decrypting password

Tags: python, encryption, base64

I want to encrypt and decrypt my password, but when I am decrypting my password, it gives me an `binascii.error: incorrect padding` error.

```
f1 = Fernet("encrypt.txt")
decrypted = f1.decrypt("b'gAAAAABeQ-2YA7zNJBA_AgVEEwcJNYMNPO3UzO9ujsInxlz_0DqIrMHlVQgRUyN9PTyGZJiN-FJ3qLJipKv2KESr3qx4yM-T2g=='", "encrypt.txt")
print(decrypted)
```

This is the error:

> "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\password generater\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Raj/PycharmProjects/password generater/encrypt.py"
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:/Users/Raj/PycharmProjects/password generater/encrypt.py", line 45, in 
>           f1 = Fernet("encrypt.txt")
>         File "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\password generater\venv\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 35, in **init**
>           key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(key)
>         File "C:\Users\Raj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
>           return b64decode(s)
>         File "C:\Users\Raj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
>           return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
>       binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use bytes instead of a string? If so, remove the double quotes:

```
f1.decrypt(b'gAAAAABeQ-2YA7zNJBA_AgVEEwcJNYMNPO3UzO9ujsInxlz_0DqIrMHlVQgRUyN9PTyGZJiN-FJ3qLJipKv2KESr3qx4yM-T2g==', 'encrypt.txt')
```